# Replace some parts of string and update the column in STANDARD SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've a year column in a table called 'Movie', some of the year values are not in the standard format(few of them are like 'I 1999', 'XV 199', etc.(**space is common in those years**)). So I wanted to remove ' ', 'X', 'V', 'I' and replace them with '' so that I can convert them to the standard format of the year.

I was able to do the replacing part by this command:

`SELECT (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((REPLACE(year, ' ', '')),'X',''),'V',''),'I','')) FROM Movie`

But I'm unable to update my column(Getting error, command not executed). Below is the command I tried.

```
UPDATE Movie
SET year = (REPLACE(REPLACE((REPLACE(year, ' ', '')),'X',''),'V',''),'I',''))
WHERE year LIKE '% %'
```

Please let me know how can I update my 'year' column. Please note I can only use **STANDARD SQL** commands.

**Update**: Attached the screenshot of the error. I am executing the SQL commands using pandas.read_sql_query() method. All standard SQL commands works nicely. But error encountered in this case.[image]please note I've removed extra parenthesis.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full text of the error message the `UPDATE` statement generates.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overusing parentheses, so something does not match.
Use this:

```
SET year = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(year, ' ', ''), 'X', ''), 'V', ''), 'I', '')
```

Comment: I've removed and tried, still getting error. I updated my question with the screenshot attached. Please have a look.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5X1fN9YKm1NKLyKfvxfson/0 If you are getting an error this is not a SQL error. The code is syntactically correct in any database that supports the function REPLACE() (as far as I know they all do).

Comment: And this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5X1fN9YKm1NKLyKfvxfson/1 for SQLite

Comment: Hi, I'm new to SQL. Can you please add the two cases that I mentioned in the question and run the query?

Comment: What cases? The code I posted fixes the error with your SQL code and this is the answer to your question. If you still get an error then the problem is with the Python code that executes this query. Post a new question about it and tag it Python.

Comment: I mean to add some observation in the table. 'I 1999', 'XV 1999'.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5X1fN9YKm1NKLyKfvxfson/2

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help. As you said it seems to be an issue with the python/pandas method.

Comment: Is there any other way we can do this?

Comment: If you mean with the Python code, I can't help you with that. If you mean the SQL code then this is the standard SQL way to do it.

Comment: "Standard" as in common. The REPLACE function is not included in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Comment: Yes common is better in this case, because as I mention in an earlier comment I can't think of a rdbms that does not support the function replace().

Comment: This comment is for those who are looking for the answer. As  @forpas said it is python error. We can't modify the data by pandas.read_sql_query() method. It only reads the data. For more details on how to handle it by python consider this link. https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-pandas-databases/ It is will be very useful for those who are to do this via python.